# Simplified Vertices frame

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

just had a quick question: I've seen artists show thier models with some sort of simplified wireframe where not all verticies are shown. This would be very helpful, needless to say, is there a way to initiate a mesh that way or viewpoint setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to something like this?

[image]

If you want to pull off this effect, select your model, go to the *Object modifiers* tab in the *Properties panel*, and add a *Wireframe* modifier. Uncheck *Replace Original* to make sure your mesh shows through underneath. Set the thickness to a value that shows the wireframe but does not cover everything. .1 should work. Watch [this](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-make-a-wireframe-render/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, can't try it but I trust.

Comment: You're most welcome.

Comment: @SilverRain how is this even relevant to the question you asked?This is how you can visualize it in rendering not in the view port and not simplified.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the subsurface modifier,You can check **Optimal Display** .

[image: SS]

Here is without (On the left) and with (In the Right)

[image: With and without]